# Facing errors when trying to add a Java API

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using the eclipse IDE and trying to use a JAVA API.

**This is the API I am trying to add. https://github.com/spoonlabs/flacoco**

It says that the API is only currently available as a snapshot and gives me the details to add it as a dependency in a pom.xml file.

I am not sure how to do this in eclipse. I have downloaded the M2Eclipse plug in and tried creating a maven project by skipping the archetypes but when I add the dependency I get too many errors.

**These are the errors that pop up : https://ibb.co/Y4gNnN8**

I do not know to resolve the issue.
If any more details related to the error is needed,please let me know.

Comment: I don't think the documentation is up-to-date, because I could find 3 versions at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.spoonlabs/flacoco. The errors don't seem to come from your single dependency.

Comment: @RobSpoor So the issue is with the API?

Comment: I don't think so. I just recreated your project, and did a command-line `mvn package`. It could build just fine. I think there's either something wrong with your IDE, or the project setup inside the IDE.

Comment: @RobSpoor I cloned the github project and downloaded maven and built it but when I run the command as they mentioned ( java -jar target/flacoco-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar --projectpath examples/can --output results.csv  --format CSV ) I get an error that says unable to access jar target/flacoco-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar.  Any idea what that could be about?

Comment: The current version in `pom.xml` is `1.0.4-SNAPSHOT`. Do you see a file `flacoco-1.0.4-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in the target folder?

Answer (score 0):

You project hierarchy, as well as the pom.xml setups are wrong.

At the pom.xml, change the group id to something like `com.<your_name>.<porject name>` then create the same package structure under src/main/java (you should end with up with something like `src/main/java/com/<your_name>/<porject_name>`).

This should fix whatever you're seeing now.

Comment: I doubt these errors come from a groupId that's technically not invalid. It won't be usable on Maven Central, but for local projects it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hi, I do not understand how to do this. Should I create three different packages named com, my name and project name?